# Excel interpreting datetime in mixture of 24 hour and AM/PM format

Tags: excel, csv, text, format

This problem is driving me crazy. I'm exporting a csv file from our email send platform to a network drive. One of the fields is a datetime field. When you view it in our email send platform's UI, it looks fine, as in the first two entries here:

[image]

And when I open up the raw file in a text editor it displays them as:

[image]

Again, looks fine.

However, when I open the CSV up in Excel, it changes one to 24H and one to an AM/PM format.

[image]

Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?

Edit: I've just noticed it adds the AM/PM to ones which happened where it doesn't end in 00 seconds.

Comment: Sometimes, Excel will fight itself & your data due to localization and/or automatic conversion issues. Have you tried the [import text wizard](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)?

Comment: I have, yes. It works, until you close the file and open it again - then it reverts to the mix of formats.

Comment: You're right - I meant the other way round; will amend. I'm in the UK, and we use dd/mm/yyyy but the software we put the CSV in converts it, so we're not bothered about it being mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: We don't actually need to open the file in Excel for it to be used in our software, but we apparently still have a problem.